# Not able to read local file in flink 1.10.0

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to read a local file in FLINK. I am getting below error.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/exceptions/YarnException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.loadCustomCommandLine(CliFrontend.java:1076)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.loadCustomCommandLines(CliFrontend.java:1030)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:957)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 5 more
2020-04-26 20:47:56,003 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies. The extended set of supported File Systems via Hadoop is not available.
```

I am using below API

```
dataStream = streamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile(params.get("input"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the file is used to read configuration parameters or is it used as source ?

PARAMS

```java
parameters = ParameterTool.fromPropertiesFile(parameters.get("configFile"));
```

SOURCE

```java
env.readFile(new TextInputFormat(new Path(inputFile)), inputFile, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 1000)
    .uid("importFile").name("Import from file").setParallelism(1).rebalance();
```

We have also developed a library for read a typed object directly from a JSON formatted file, and the file is parsed all together and not row by row. The library is available on maven. [streaming-flink-file-source](https://github.com/fabricalab/streaming-flink-file-source)

```java
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
final JsonFileConsumerConfig<BusinessConfiguration> config = new JsonFileConsumerConfig<>(BusinessConfiguration.class)
        .setPath("s3://<YOUR_AWESOME_FILE>.json");
final JsonFileConsumer<BusinessConfiguration> consumer = new JsonFileConsumer<>(config);
env.setParallelism(parallelism);
consumer.getJsonFileStream(env)
        .addSink(...);
env.execute();
```